# embed video file in my html file

Tags: html, embedded-video

i want to embed video file in my html file and that video file is saved in same  folder where my html page is saved?so how can i embed that video?

Answer (score 1):

I would advise using HTML5 to do this:

```
<video src="myvideo.avi"/>
```

This will work for Firefox 3.0+, Chrome and Safari. Not sure about the early IE (Internet Explorers). It also avoids having to use Flash to render a video window.

W3C Schools [has a good article on the use of the video tag](http://www.w3schools.com/html5/html5_reference.asp)

Comment: It will work in those browsers iif the video is in a formant that they all support (good luck with that), it won't work in any final version of IE (I'm not sure about 9, but 8 is not 'early' and certainly doesn't support it) and W3Schools does not have a good article on it, it has a very lightweight and incomplete reference.

Answer (score 0):

W3schools has a great reference on the <video> tag here:http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp

Another solution is to upload your videos to youtube and then embed the video on your site. It takes less server space on your part, it is widely supported, and you can get discovered easier.